# Unable to connect to WLADM

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to install and setup MobileFirst. SO i was able to install WAS ND, create a server, Install Mobilefirst Server, Install database, Create database and now i am trying to create a runtime with the configuration tool.

Below is the Database screenshot which proves that the database exist

[image]

This is a screenshot of the creating admin configuration and also it show that the port number is ok

[image]

This is a screen shot of the database additional extra setting which is checking for the database WLADM70 which i have given, validation happened without problem but its always in the checking for the database state.

[image]

Comment: The screenshot shows only WLR70.WLADM70 is indeed present? Was it created in the first place? Is it possible you have entered it wrongly?

Comment: @VivinK I have changed the image as per your doubt, so WLADM70 is present. You can see it. Please help me to isolve it now

Comment: Was WLADM70 created using ant scripts or manually? Could permissions be an issue?
Configuration tools creates log files. Verify if there are error messages in the logs.
Also, provide details of your MobileFirst version, DB version details, OS details.